# sed can't match 0 or 1 time

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm writing a bash script on Cent OS7. Now I need to use `sed` to remove all lines which don't contain `.jpg` or `.jpeg`.

Here is my script:

```
sed -i -e '/\.jp(e)?g/!d' myfile
```

But it will delete all lines, which means that it doesn't work as expected.

However, if I do `sed -i -e '/\.jpg/!d' myfile` or `sed -i -e '/\.jpeg/!d' myfile`. Both of them work well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Captured group (`()`) and the quantifier `?` (match the preceding token 0 or 1 time) comes (at least) with ERE (Extended RegEx), not BRE (Basic RegEx).

`sed` by default uses BRE, so the tokens are being treated literally.

To enable ERE, use `-E` (or `-r` if available) with `sed`:

```
sed -E '/\.jp(e)?g/!d' myfile
```

Capturing `e` is redundant here:

```
sed -E '/\.jpe?g/!d' myfile
```

---

Note that, you can use ERE tokens from BRE by escaping them with `\`, so the following would work too:

```
sed '/\.jp\(e\)\?g/!d' myfile
sed '/\.jpe\?g/!d' myfile
```

Again, this does not look as clean as just using one option i.e. `-E`. Only case where you will want this is portability.

Comment: with `-i` in macOS it is `sed -i '' -E '/\.jp(e)?g/!d' myfile`

Answer (score 3):

Use regex in the `sed` command may meet your requirement, zero or one 'e' would be filtered as shown in followed.

`sed -i -e '/jpe\?g/!d' myfile`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\.jp\(e\|\)g/!d' file
```

Use alternation where one of the alternates is empty.

Perhaps easier to see if the alternates are listed:

```
sed '/\.jpeg\|\.jpg/!d' file
```

However as has already been stated, use `?`:

```
sed '/\.jpe\?g/!d' file
```

N.B. `*` is zero or more i.e.

```
sed '/\.jpe*g/!d' file
```

would allow `.jpeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeg`